In C, extract mantissa of a double as a long long in portable way
Function frexp(3) returns the normalized mantissa xm of a double x, with a value in [0.5,1.0), unless x=0. So I can convert it to a long long as follows:
    int ie; // will be set in next line
    const double xm = frexp(x, &ie); // from math.h; sets xm and ie
    const long long ix = ldexp(xm, 53); // xm*2**53, rounded to long integer

However, this feels less than optimum because of the intermediary double value returned by function ldexp(3). Is there a more direct, and no less portable, way of extracting ix from x?

That's basically the way I do it.  I know what you mean about "feels less than optimum", but frexp really is the portable way of busting up a double.  It used to bug me that frexp gave me the significand as another double, but I've gotten used to it, and there are decent reasons for that choice.

I think I've used scalbn rather than ldexp to do the final scaling, though.

Never heard of scalbn, looks good, thanks.

man scalbn(3) talks of "FLT_RADIX (probably 2)".  Amazing. If the C standard does not even require base 2, then we need to qualify what we understand by portability here. Probably no less than IEEE 754. Would that requirement open doors for other solutions?

Yes, C does accommodate floating-point representations having radix different from 2, though these are very rare in modern C implementations.  frexp() computes specifically a base-2 factorization of a double, and I suspect that it returns the fraction as a normalized double exactly because it might not be exactly representable as an integer if FLT_RADIX is different from 2. This means that yes, you do need to define your terms carefully.  When you say "mantissa", do you mean it in an as-if base 2 sense, or in a bits actually stored sense?

That also means that radix-insensitive frexp does not be pair well with radix-sensitive scalb / scalbn if you want to accommodate the floating-point radix being different from 2.

@JoachimW const long long ix = ldexp(xm, 53); // xm*2**53, rounded to long integer deserves improved comment: 1) it is not rounded, but truncated and 2) it is to a long long, not long.

@JoachimW "intermediary double value" --> say you wanted to do the same with long double and its mantissa significand was wider than 64-bits.  What integer type would you use?  Note: the significand of a double could be wider than 64-bits too.

@JoachimW Regarding your deleted question - It's related to LWG2381 and the expected effect was clarified in the newly released C++ standard (C++23). It seems only MSVC (of the big four) have implemented it yet though.

Thank you very much, Ted. I deleted because I felt harrassed by unexplained close votes.


Is there a more direct, and no less portable, way of extracting ix from x?

No.
That's basically the way to do it. It "feels less than optimum", but frexp() really is the portable way of busting up a double. It used to bug me that frexp() gave me the significand as another double, but I've gotten used to it, and there are decent reasons for that choice.
@Steve Summit
#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>

if (isfinite(x)) {
  int ie;
  double xm = frexp(x, &ie);
  long long ix = scalbn(xm, DBL_MANT_DIG);
}

Portability: Note that the number of bits in the double significand may exceed the widest integer type.
